# Canon PIXIMA 5150 Printing issue

Tags: printing, canon

The printer is installed. When i start printing i see that in the CUPS :

```
Canon-MG5100-series-57  Unknown     Withheld    1k  Unknown     completed at
```

Mon May 4 08:25:47 2020

But nothing was printed.

Could you please advise on possible fix.
Thank you!

Comment: What's in `/var/log/cups/...` logs?

Comment: 'localhost - - [06/May/2020:20:03:38 +0300] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 151 Cancel-Subscription client-error-not-found
localhost - - [06/May/2020:20:58:21 +0300] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 187 Renew-Subscription client-error-not-found
localhost - - [06/May/2020:21:56:41 +0300] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 187 Renew-Subscription client-error-not-found
localhost - - [06/May/2020:22:10:02 +0300] "POST /printers/Canon-MG5100-series HTTP/1.1" 200 243 Create-Job successful-ok
localhost - - [06/May/2020:22:10:02 +0300] "POST /printers/Canon-MG5100-series HTTP/1.1" 200 26794 Send-Document successful-ok'